# How to configure IIS settings for ASP.NET IIS Container?

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, iis

I am converting an ASP.NET API that currently runs on a windows server running IIS 8, to run inside of a docker container using the following IIS image:
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.7.1

I have the API working correctly however, some calls can take over a minute to send a response. The current IIS setup has a connection timeout of 120s so these long calls complete fine. However, When the same call is made against the docker containers the client disconnects after ~60s and NGINX serves an HTTP 499 Error.

I would like to set the connection timeout to match the current IIS setup (120s) but since the IIS is containerized, I am not sure how to make these changes.

How can you configure IIS settings for a docker container?

Comment: Use the PowerShell cmdlets to manipulate IIS settings in your Dockerfile.

Comment: Could you be more specific @LexLi? Are you saying there are specific RUN commands that can be passed into the Dockerfile? Or that there are powershell commands that can be run after the container is running?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more research I found that all IIS settings can be configured in the projects Web.config file.
More information on those settings can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/web-config?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configuration-of-iis-with-webconfig)

Another way is to set up IIS Remote Management for the container.